# Condition for $k$ so that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1 - k(1-2^{-k})^{(n/k)} = 1$

Tags: calculus

I'm going over a proof, whose last step is the following statement:

If $ k = (1-\epsilon )\cdot \log_{2}(n)$

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1-k(1-2^{-k})^{(n/k)} = 1$$

I'm trying to understand why this k ensures that the limit converges to 1.

Comment: I see only one statement, but not so-called *"last step"*. Please, add your work so that somebody can help you check that.

Comment: The rest is irrelevant to this statement in the proof. The prior steps don't change the fact regarding the condition for k that satifies that this limit converges to 0. I can change the description in the question to "why this statement is true" if that helps...

Comment: Your title asks to find conditions for $k$ for that limit to be $0$. But in the body, you ask about the last step. So, I conclude you did some work on finding conditions for $k$ and asking to verify the answer. In my previous comment, I intended to say that adding your work will save others' time from re-doing the same work you have done. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: I was unclear then. I meant that I'm going over a proof. The last statement in the proof is the limit and they give a potential k that ensures the limit converges to 0. I will edit my post to clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the limit is $1$, for $0<\epsilon<1$, take a look at:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+when+n+goes+to+infinity+1-0.5*log2%28n%29%281-1%2F%282%5E%280.5*log2%28n%29%29%29%29%5E%28n%2F%280.5*log2%28n%29%29%29

Lets work over the limit:
\begin{align}
lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}[1-(1-\epsilon)log_2(n)[1-\frac{1}{2^{(1-\epsilon)log_2(n)}}]^{\frac{n}{(1-\epsilon)log_2(n)}}]&=\\
lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}[1-(1-\epsilon)log_2(n)[1-\frac{1}{n^{(1-\epsilon)}})]^{n^{1-\epsilon}\frac{n^{\epsilon}}{(1-\epsilon)log_2(n)}}]&=\\
lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}[1-(1-\epsilon)log_2(n)e^{-\frac{n^{\epsilon}}{(1-\epsilon)log_2(n)}}]&=1-0
\end{align}

Note that $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n}=e^{-1}$ (this is a famous result see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_limits)

Since $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}log_2(n)e^{ -\frac{n^\epsilon}{(1-\epsilon)log_2(n)} }=0$. To show that this last limit is $0$, we can use the fact that $e^x>e^y$ if $x>y$. For $n$ large enought, we have that $-log(n)>-\frac{n^\epsilon}{(1-\epsilon)log_2(n)}$, sice logarithms grow solower than linear functions. Hence:

$$0\leq log_2(n)e^{ -\frac{n^\epsilon}{(1-\epsilon)log_2(n)} }\leq log_2(n)e^{ -log(n)}$$

Computing this limit:
$$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{ log_2(n)}{e^{ log(n) }}= lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{log_2(n)}{n}=0$$

Comment: You're right I wrote 0 but in my mind I was referring to the second part.

Comment: @ec2604 Okay, hope it made thinks more clear. Let me know if you want more details.

Comment: Two questions:
1. Can you transition to $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(n)*(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n\cdot g(n)} = lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(n)\cdot e^{-g(n)}$?
2. Assuming 1 works, why does the last part converge to 0?

Comment: @ec2604 I will edit the answer for those questions.

Comment: Just to note I understand that $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (1-\frac{x}{n})^{n} = e^{-x}$, In question 1 I'm asking whether this still applies when x is also a function of n.

Comment: @ec2604 yes, in general $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-\frac{1}{g(n)})^{g(n)}=e^{-1}$, if ($lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g(n)=\infty$)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116036/discussion-between-ec2604-and-jorge).

Answer (score 0):

We have that by $k = (1-\epsilon )\log_{2}(n)$

$$1-k(1-2^{-k})^{\frac n k}=1-(1-\epsilon )\cdot \log_{2}(n)\left(1-\frac1{n^{1-\epsilon}}\right)^{\frac n {(1-\epsilon ) \log_{2}(n)}} \to 1$$

indeed since as $x \to 0^+$ we have $\log (1-x) \le -x$

$$\left(1-\frac1{n^{1-\epsilon}}\right)^{\frac n {(1-\epsilon )\cdot \log_{2}(n)}} =e^{\frac n {(1-\epsilon )\cdot \log_{2}(n)}\log\left(1-\frac1{n^{1-\epsilon}}\right)}\le e^{-\frac {n^{\epsilon}} {(1-\epsilon ) \log_{2}(n)}}$$

and then

$$(1-\epsilon )\cdot \log_{2}(n)\left(1-\frac1{n^{1-\epsilon}}\right)^{\frac n {(1-\epsilon ) \log_{2}(n)}} \le (1-\epsilon )\log_{2}(n)e^{-\frac {n^{\epsilon}} {(1-\epsilon ) \log_{2}(n)}}=$$

$$=\frac{\frac {n^{\epsilon}} {(1-\epsilon ) \log_{2}(n)}}{e^{\frac {n^{\epsilon}} {(1-\epsilon ) \log_{2}(n)}}} \cdot \frac{\left[(1-\epsilon )\log_{2}(n)\right]^2}{n^{\epsilon}} \to 0\cdot 0=0$$